# Regex for java's String.matches method?

Tags: java, regex, string

Basically my question is this, why is:

```
String word = "unauthenticated";
word.matches("[a-z]");
```

returning false?  (Developed in java1.6)

Basically I want to see if a string passed to me has alpha chars in it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `String.matches()` function matches your regular expression against the *whole* string (as if your regex had `^` at the start and `$` at the end). If you want to search for a regular expression somewhere within a string, use [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()).

The correct method depends on what you want to do:

1. Check to see whether your input string consists *entirely* of alphabetic characters (`String.matches()` with `[a-z]+`)
2. Check to see whether your input string contains *any* alphabetic character (and perhaps some others) (`Matcher.find()` with `[a-z]`)

Answer (score 4):

Your code is checking to see if the word matches one character.  What you want to check is if the word matches any number of alphabetic characters like the following:

```
word.matches("[a-z]+");
```

Comment: I never saw the + symbol in any examples before.  The java didn't like me using * for some reason, but + is working.  Thanks.

Comment: @Shaun, the `+` means 1 or more of preceding element.

Comment: @Shaun83 - Java / java regexes will have no problems with a `*` instead of `+` either.  Maybe you ARE losing it ... :-)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0.  

I must've had it in the wrong place though cause its worked for other regex's.

Comment: Index zero is the beginning of the string, so yes, you did have it in the wrong place.

Comment: To expand on @AlanMoore's comment, * doesn't match any character, it matches the preceding character zero ore more times. If it is at the start of the regex, then there is no preceding character, hence it is in the wrong place. To match the beginning you're after something like '.*', where dot matches any (printable?) character.

Answer (score 1):

with `[a-z]` you math for ONE character.

What you’re probably looking for is `[a-z]*`