# How to check whether a string contains the search items

Tags: java, regex, string, search-engine, contains

I have a `String` and a `String[]` filled with search items.

How can I check whether my `String` contains all of the search items?

Here is an example:

Case 1:

```
String text = "this is a stupid test";
String[] searchItems = new String[2];
searchItems[0] = "stupid";
searchItems[1] = "test";
```

Case 2:

```
String text = "this is a stupid test";
String[] searchItems = new String[2];
searchItems[0] = "stupid";
searchItems[1] = "tes";
```

In case 1, the method should return `true`, but in case 2 the method should return `false`.

Comment: Have you tried `.contains()`?

Comment: won't work he needs the entire word match

Comment: He would have to step through the array and verify that `text.contains(searchItems[i])`, but it would work if implemented correctly.

Comment: @PatrickJAbareII it won't.

Comment: This needs more tests. For example: `String text="I need a car, right now."; String[] searchItems = { "car", "now" };`, the `flag` should be `true` or `false`?

Comment: Did you consider to make a hashmap and then check if a word is in the hashmap with containsValue() method?

Comment: @Luiigi Mendoza: the flag should be true in your case/example. The flag should only be true if text matches all patterns

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using [word boundaries](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) in regex:

```
boolean result = true;
for (String item : searchItems) {
    String pattern = ".*\\b" + item + "\\b.*";
    // by using the &&, result will be true only if text matches all patterns.
    result = result && text.matches(pattern);
}
```

The boundaries ensure that the search terms will only be matched if the whole word is present in your text. So, `"tes"` will not match against `"test"` because `"\btes\b"` is not a substring of `"\btest\b"`.

Comment: there is a little something: result=result&&text.matches("(.*)"+pattern+"(.*)") instead of:  result = result && text.matches(pattern);

Comment: @user3300710 Good call. This is actually semi-unusual for regex, as a match normally signifies containment unless you anchor your pattern to the beginning and end of the string (ie `^pattern$`). But Java's [String.matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) does in fact require the `.*`, so I will adjust my answer.

Comment: @user3300710 [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4405134/2479481) brought the [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) method to my attention. You can use it if you want to check for containment automatically. Though, it is perhaps [more verbose](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would try to split the string with spaces and then loop thought all the splinted parts.

Something like this for your code to work:

```
String text = "this is a stupid test";
List<String> searchItems = new ArrayList<String>();
searchItems.add("stupid");
searchItems.add("test");
for(String word : test.split(" ")) {
   if(searchItems.contains(word)){
      //do your stuff when the condition is true ...
   } else {
      //do your stuff when the condition is false ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make an array of all words in the text.
Then check it with 2 for loops if the textArray contains all the searchterms.

```
public boolean search(String text, String[] searchItems) {

    String[] textArray = text.split(" ");

    for(String searchitem: searchItems) {

       boolean b = false;

       for(String word : textArray) {

           if(word.equals(searchitem)) {
               b = true;
               break;
           }

        }

     // text doesn't contain searchitem
     if(!b) return false;

     }

     return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text.matches(".*\\b" + searchItems[0] + "\\b.*")
```

Note: `"\\b"` will ensure that only 'whole words' are matched.

Answer (score -2):

```
public boolean findIfAllItemsMatch(String[] searchItems, String text) {
    boolean allItemsMatch = true;
    for (String item_ : searchItems) {
        if(!text.contains(item_)) {  
              allItemsMatch = false;
              break;
         }
    }
    return allItemsMatch;
}
```